# Issues with .grid in Tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter, grid

I am VERY new to coding/Python, but basically I am trying to move a button and label around using .grid, however, the button and label in the `StartPage` class just won't move to where I ask (or even at all).
Everything in the `BMR` class works fine (although the positions you see aren't the final positions, I was just checking).

What is the difference? Why do they not appear at the same position if I give the same details in both classes?

```py
import tkinter as tk

    class initials(tk.Tk):
        def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
            tk.Tk.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
            container = tk.Frame(self)
            container.pack(side='top', fill='both', expand= True)
            container.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
            container.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
            self.frames = {}
            for F in (StartPage, BMR):
                frame = F(container, self)
                self.frames[F] = frame
                frame.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky='nsew')
            self.show_frame(StartPage)

        def show_frame(self, cont):
            frame = self.frames[cont]
            frame.tkraise() 

    class StartPage(tk.Frame):  #GRID WON'T WORK HOW I WANT IT TO
            def __init__(self, parent, controller):
                tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
                label = tk.Label(self, text="Start Page")
                label.grid(column=3, row=3, sticky='we')
                button = tk.Button(self, text="Calculate BMR", 
                    command=lambda: controller.show_frame(BMR))
                button.grid(row=4, column=3, sticky='we')

    class BMR(tk.Frame): #GRID WORKS PERFECTLY
            def __init__(self, parent, controller):
                tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
                label = tk.Label(self, text="BMR Calculator")
                label.grid(column=1,row=1)
                button1 = tk.Button(self, text="Back to Home", 
                    command=lambda: controller.show_frame(StartPage))
                button1.grid(column=2, row=2)
                submit = tk.Button(self, text="Calculate")
                submit.grid(column=3, row=3)
                var1 = tk.IntVar()
                tk.Checkbutton(self, text='Male', bg='white', variable=var1).grid(column=4, row=4)
                var2= tk.IntVar()
                tk.Checkbutton(self, text='Female', bg='white', variable=var2).grid(column=5, row=5)    
                height_inp = tk.Entry(self, width=20, bg="white").grid(column=6, row=6)

    app = initials()
    app.mainloop()
```

Comment: Since you're using sticky='we', how do you actually want to place the label and the button?

Comment: @Namandeep_Kaur, To be honest, this was after I gave up, so the column 3 row 3 can be ignored. However, my aim was to put it in the middle of the frame at the top.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
class StartPage(tk.Frame):  
    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        label = tk.Label(self, text="Start Page", width = 80)
        # Added width property in the line above
        # and changed sticky property to N
        label.grid(row = 3, column=3, sticky = 'N')
        label.width = 20
        button = tk.Button(self, text="Calculate BMR", 
            command=lambda: controller.show_frame(BMR))
        button.grid(row=4, column=3)
        # Removed sticky property for the button
```

I understand this is how you wish to position the label and the button.
Pleaase see the comments. You can edit the value for the width property and make it suitable for your frame.